# How to clear Office-ui-fabric-react fields after object has been added to list?

Tags: spfx, pnp, react

I have a simple list that gathers info from two text fields, a drop down and a people picker. I am able to submit to my custom list. I have set the state back to the defaultValue, which I have defined in state, once the list has been submitted. If I try to submit again, I catch the errors that I have defined stating that the fields have empty values, yet they look populated.

Is there a simple way to clear all values from Office Fabric UI input fields?

Render Method:

```
        <div className={styles.inputContainer}>
            <label className={styles.labelWidth}>Company name: </label>
              <TextField 
                name="companyName"
                onChanged={(e) => {this._handleName(e);}}
                defaultValue={this.state.defaultValue.companyName}
              />       
            <br/>
        </div>

        <div className={styles.inputContainer}>
            <label className={styles.labelWidth}>Total Revenue: </label>
                <TextField 
                  name="revenue"
                  type="number"
                  onChanged={this._handleRevenue}
                  defaultValue={this.state.defaultValue.revenue}
                />
            <br/>
        </div>

        <div className={styles.inputContainer}>
            <label className={styles.labelWidth}>Department: </label>
            <Dropdown
                placeHolder="Select an Option"
                label=""
                id="component"
                selectedKey={this.state.defaultValue.department ? this.state.defaultValue.department.key : undefined}
                ariaLabel="Basic dropdown example"
                options={[
                    { key: '', text: 'Select an option'},
                    { key: 'Information Technology', text: 'Information Technology' },
                    { key: 'Cyber Security', text: 'Cyber Security' },
                    { key: 'Infrastructure', text: 'Infrastructure' },
                    { key: 'Logistics', text: 'Logistics'},
                    { key: 'Other', text: 'Other'}
                ]}
                onChanged={this._handleDepartment}
            />
            <br/>
        </div>

        <div className={styles.inputContainer}>
          <label className={styles.labelWidth}>Department Head:</label>
            <PeoplePicker
              context={this.props.context}
              titleText=""
              personSelectionLimit={1}
              groupName={""}
              showtooltip={false}
              isRequired={true}
              ensureUser={true}
              disabled={false}
              defaultSelectedUsers={['']}
              selectedItems={this._getManager} 
            />
          </div>
```

onChange Methods:

```
    private _getManager(items: any[]) {
        this.state.defaultValue.departmentHeadId.pop(),
        this.state.defaultValue.departmentHeadName.pop();
        for (let item in items) 
        {   
          this.state.defaultValue.departmentHeadId.push(items[item].id),
          this.state.defaultValue.departmentHeadName.push(items[item].text);
        }
      }  

      private _handleName = (fieldInput:string) => {
        var input = {...this.state.defaultValue};
        input.companyName = fieldInput;
        this.setState({
          defaultValue:input
        });
      }

      private _handleRevenue = (value: string): void => {
        var input = {...this.state.defaultValue};
        input.revenue = value;
        this.setState({
          defaultValue:input
        });
      }

      private _handleDepartment = (item:IDropdownOption): void => {
        var input = {...this.state.defaultValue};
        input.department = item;
        this.setState({
          defaultValue:input
        });
      }
```

Setting state back to default:

```
    private _closeDialog = (): void => {
      this.setState({ 
        hideDialog: true,
        status:'',
        defaultValue: {
          companyName:'',
          revenue:'',
          department: {
            key:'',
            text:''
          },
          departmentHeadId: [],
          departmentHeadName: [],
        }
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

by changing

```
defaultValue={this.state.defaultValue.revenue}
```

to

```
value={this.state.defaultValue.revenue}
```

therefore making it a controlled component seemed to do the trick for the textFields.

For the DropDown field I added a defaultValue and this corrected the issue after submit.

For the pnp PeoplePicker I added

```
ref={(e) => {this.myPicker=e;}}
```

to the component and then, on addItem(), set the state of the selected persons property from the reference created.

```
public myPicker: PeoplePicker;

this.myPicker.setState ({
  selectedPersons: []
});
```

Comment: Adding reference of the picker, did the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Bind your control's value to state. When you clear out state, the controls will clear out as well.

```
<TextField 
  name="revenue"
  type="number"
  onChanged={this._handleRevenue}
  defaultValue={this.state.defaultValue.revenue}
  value={this.state.whatever}
  />
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've read not to do it this way and also been told not to have a value and a default value within the same input field.

Comment: Also peoplePicker and dropDown do not support value attributes in my instance.